# How to get a non-linear layout in class diagram?

Tags: plantuml

A class diagram seems to always be linear - either in horizontal or, if I add `left to right direction`, vertical.

[image: Horizontal Diagram]

However, in many cases the layout could do a better use of the screen space. Check this one out:

[image: Star Diagram]

This last diagram could easily have A as a center in the middle of the screen and then have all other classes *around* it.

I know that PlantUML uses Graphviz behind the curtains to do the layout, which supports a [variety of styles](https://graphviz.org/gallery/). So, can I tell PlantUML to do something smarter when it comes to class diagrams?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like [image: centered A class]

produced by

```
B -l-* A
C -l-* A
A *-r- D
A *-r- E
```

I defined the classes in ascending order A, B, ..E. Check out the [Layout](https://crashedmind.github.io/PlantUMLHitchhikersGuide/layout/layout.html) Section of the new Hitchhiker's Guide for details. Or the Section *Changing arrows direction* in the [class diagram page](https://plantuml.com/class-diagram) of plantuml.com.

(Tested in Linux Mint 20 Ulyana, Emacs 26.3, org mode 9.3.1, PlantUml 1.2018.13 src block, graphviz 2.43.0)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of your second example, we see it has horizontal associations, e.g., `A *- B`. If you always use **vertical** associations, e.g. `A *-- B`, GraphViz does always does a better job:

```
A *-- B
A *-- C
A *-- D
A *-- E
A *-- F
A *-- G
A *-- H
A *-- I
A *-- J
```

[image]

Comment: I'll test this, it seems exactly what I was looking for!